Why is my move assignment operator not working properly? It appears it's messing rest of couts in main as well
main.cpp
int main()
{
    Mystring larry3 = "larry3"; //will call no-arg ctor not move ctor.
    Mystring larry4 = larry3; // deep copy ctor is being called correctly
    std::cout <<"before" << endl;
    larry4 = "larry4"; // move assignment operator is being called correctly
    larry4 = Mystring{"larry4Again"}; // move assignment should be called -- but things
                                      // seems to be messed after this line
    larry4.display(); // this is also not working
    std::cout <<"after" << endl; // this is also not working

    return 0;
}

Mystring.cpp
//
// Created by kumarg on 17-11-2024.
//

#include "Mystring.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//no-arg ctror
Mystring::Mystring()
  :str{nullptr} {
  str = new char[1];
  *str = '\0'; //
  cout << "no-arg ctor" << endl;
}

//arg ctor
Mystring::Mystring(const char *s)
  :str{nullptr}{
  if(s == nullptr) { //if s points to nullptr then do same thing as no-arg ctor
    this->str = new char[1]; // this->str or str is same used in 3rd line from here
    *str = '\0';
  } else {
    str = new char[std::strlen(s) + 1];
    std::strcpy(this->str, s);
  }
  std::cout << "arg-ctor" <<endl;
}

//dtor
Mystring::~Mystring() {
  std::cout << "dtor called: " << str << endl;
  delete []str;
}

void Mystring::display() const {
  std::cout << this->str << endl;
}

//copy ctor - deep
Mystring::Mystring(const Mystring &source)
  :str{nullptr} {
  std::cout << "deep copy ctor" << endl;
  str = new char[std::strlen(source.str) +1];
  std::strcpy(this->str, source.str);
}

//move ctor
Mystring::Mystring(Mystring &&source)
  :str{source.str} {
  cout << "move ctor" << endl;
  source.str = nullptr;
}

//copy assignment operator implementation
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(const Mystring &rhs) {
  std::cout << "copy assignment operator" << endl;
  //check if both are same already
  if(this == &rhs)
    return *this;
  delete []str;
  str = new char[std::strlen(rhs.str) + 1];
  std::strcpy(this->str, rhs.str);
  return *this;
}

//move assignment operator
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(Mystring &&rhs) {
  std::cout << "move assignment operator" << endl;
  if(this == &rhs)
    return *this;
  delete []str;
  str = rhs.str;
  rhs.str = nullptr;
  return *this;
}

Mystring.h
//
// Created by kumarg on 16-11-2024.
//      

#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mystring {
private:
    char *str;
public:
    Mystring(); // default ctor
    Mystring(const char *source); //parameter ctor
    ~Mystring();
    Mystring(const Mystring &source); //copy ctor
    Mystring(Mystring &&source) noexcept; //move ctor

    void display() const;
    Mystring operator-(); // unary - operator overloading
    bool operator==(Mystring &rhs); // assignment operator overloading
    bool operator!=(Mystring &rhs); // !- operator overloading


    bool operator<(Mystring &lhs);
    bool operator>(Mystring &lhs);
    Mystring operator+(Mystring &lhs);
    //assignment (=) operator overloading, remember this called when we do s2 = s1(both are initilaized already)
    // = operator can be overloaded in 2 ways, copy and move, if l-value thenp copy will be called, if r-value move will be called
    Mystring &operator=(const Mystring &rhs);
    // = op overloading by move
    Mystring &operator=(Mystring &&rhs);
    //Mystring &operator+=(Mystring &lhs);    
};

#endif //MYSTRING_H

My code executes as per expectation until this line in main:
larry4 = "larry4";
But, after this line:
larry4 = Mystring{"larry4Again"};
I was expecting an arg-ctor call and then a move assignment call. So I was expecting a cout from the arg-ctor and then a cout from the move operator assignment call. And then finally I was expecting cout from main.
None of that is happening, and I don't understand why.

First of all, please try to create a [mre] to show us. Then copy-paste (as text) the actual and expected output from that code into the question.

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but shouldn't the move constructor in the .cpp file also be specified as noexcept? Definitely getting compiler errors on godbolt if I paste your .h, .cpp and main (in that order) into a single file.

The problem has nothing to do with your move assignment, but rather that in your Mystring destructor (Mystring::~Mystring) you do not check if str is null when attempting to print it in this line:
std::cout << "dtor called: " << str << endl;

As you can see here, operator<< overload for char* does not support a null pointer:

If s is a null pointer, the behavior is undefined.

You can fix it by changing the print statement to be:
if (str) {
    std::cout << "dtor called: " << str << endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "dtor called (null)" << endl;
}

Live demo

The problem comes before this line:
larry4 = Mystring{"larry4Again"};
Check that str exists before printing it in your destructor, or don't try to print it in the dtor since your move assignment operator makes it a nullptr.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Mystring {
private:
public:
    char *str;
    Mystring(); // default ctor
    Mystring(const char *source); //parameter ctor
    ~Mystring();
    Mystring(const Mystring &source); //copy ctor
    Mystring(Mystring &&source); //move ctor

    void display() const;
    Mystring operator-(); // unary - operator overloading
    bool operator==(Mystring &rhs); // assignment operator overloading
    bool operator!=(Mystring &rhs); // !- operator overloading


    bool operator<(Mystring &lhs);
    bool operator>(Mystring &lhs);
    Mystring operator+(Mystring &lhs);
    //assignment (=) operator overloading, remember this called when we do s2 = s1(both are initilaized already)
    // = operator can be overloaded in 2 ways, copy and move, if l-value thenp copy will be called, if r-value move will be called
    Mystring &operator=(const Mystring &rhs);
    // = op overloading by move
    Mystring &operator=(Mystring &&rhs);
    //Mystring &operator+=(Mystring &lhs);   
};

//no-arg ctror
Mystring::Mystring()
  :str{nullptr} {
  str = new char[1];
  *str = '\0'; //
  cout << "no-arg ctor" << endl;
}

//arg ctor
Mystring::Mystring(const char *s)
  :str{nullptr}{
  if(s == nullptr) { //if s points to nullptr then do same thing as no-arg ctor
    this->str = new char[1]; // this->str or str is same used in 3rd line from here
    *str = '\0';
  } else {
    str = new char[std::strlen(s) + 1];
    std::strcpy(this->str, s);
  }
  std::cout << "arg-ctor" <<endl;
}

//dtor
Mystring::~Mystring() {
  std::cout << "dtor called: " << endl;
  delete []str;
}

void Mystring::display() const {
  std::cout << this->str << endl;
}

//copy ctor - deep
Mystring::Mystring(const Mystring &source)
  :str{nullptr} {
  std::cout << "deep copy ctor" << endl;
  str = new char[std::strlen(source.str) +1];
  std::strcpy(this->str, source.str);
}

//move ctor
Mystring::Mystring(Mystring &&source)
  :str{source.str} {
  cout << "move ctor" << endl;
  source.str = nullptr;
}

//copy assignment operator implementation
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(const Mystring &rhs) {
  std::cout << "copy assignment operator" << endl;
  //check if both are same already
  if(this == &rhs)
    return *this;
  delete []str;
  str = new char[std::strlen(rhs.str) + 1];
  std::strcpy(this->str, rhs.str);
  return *this;
}

//move assignment operator
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(Mystring &&rhs) {
  std::cout << "move assignment operator" ;
  if(this == &rhs){
  std::cout << " on same object" << endl;
  return *this;}
  delete []str;
  str = rhs.str;
  rhs.str = 0;
  std::cout << " with different objects => new str is " << str << endl;
  return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Mystring larry3 = "larry3"; //will call no-arg ctor not move ctor.
    Mystring larry4 = larry3; // deep copy ctor is being called correctly
    std::cout <<"before" << endl;
    std::cout <<"larry3 = "<< larry3.str <<"; larry4 = "<<larry4.str<< endl;
    larry4 = Mystring("larry4"); // move assignment operator is being called correctly
    std::cout <<"larry3 = "<< larry3.str <</*"; larry4 = "<<larry4.str<<*/ endl;
    larry4 = "larry5";
    
    std::cout <<"larry3 = "<< larry3.str <<"; larry4 = "<<larry4.str<< endl;
    larry4 = "larry4Again"; // move assignment should be called -- but things
                                      // seems to be messed after this line
                                      
    std::cout <<"larry3 = "<< larry3.str <<"; larry4 = "<<larry4.str<< endl;
    larry4.display(); // this is also not working
    std::cout <<"after" << endl; // this is also not working
    
    std::cout <<"larry3 = "<< larry3.str <<"; larry4 = "<<larry4.str<< endl;

    return 0;
}

